# Spring Boot Logo Does Not Show Up When I run Tomcat Startup.bat and 404 when trying to hit url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

The IDE I am developing on is Intellij.

I am trying to launch my spring project with an external version of tomcat. I have created the base of the project and did a "mvn clean package" command in the console to generate a war file. This is what is contained in my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myName</groupId>
    <artifactId>ResumeWebsite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ResumeWebsite</name>
    <description>Website for containing personal projects</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyWebsite</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The following screenshots are what I have in my classes as well as what tomcat displays in command prompt when running the batch file.

[image: ResumeWebsiteApplicationClass]

[image: ServletInitializerClass]

[image: TestControllerClass]

[image: TomcatRunningScreenShot]

When I try to go to the route localhost:8080/MyWebsite/print I get a 404 error. I had then tried localhost:8080/print and still get a 404 error.
[image: 404Request]

In my server.xml file for my tomcat server this is what is shown for my Http and AJP connectors

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443"
               secretRequired="false" />
```

This is also what is contained in my webapps folder for my tomcat server.
[image: WebAppFolderScreenshot]

If any more information is needed please feel free to ask. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tomcat10 is JakartaEE not JavaEE. Use Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat10 is JakartaEE not JavaEE. Use Tomcat 9. As stated by the person who commented to my post. This fixed my issues.